# Update react-router when next/router changes state

Tags: react-router, next.js

I have a Next.js app with several pages with separate pages with their own `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` inside the Next app. ([This is the reason](https://dev.to/arnemahl/comment/ih2b) for that.)

Using `Link` from `react-router-dom` works fine, the changes propagate only throughout components within the `BrowserRouter`, which works for our case. (When linking to a page with another `BrowserRouter` we use `next/link`, which also works fine.)

However, we are now creating a component to be shared between pages using different `BrowserRouter`s, so I've used `next/link` within that shared component.

**The problem** with that is that the changed state of the Next router does not propagate into the `BrowserRouter`.

Minimal reproduction of the problem here: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-react-router-not-updating-uy8bj
The `BrowserRouter` is in `components/App.js`.

[image: Problem as reproduced in Codesandbox]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `next/router` state within the `BrowserRouter` as well. The least invasive  fix is to push to the history of the `BrowserRouter` when it is out of sync with the `next/router`. You can do that in a component like this:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter as useNextRouter } from "next/router";

function RouteIfStaleUrl(props) {
  const nextRouter = useNextRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.match.url !== nextRouter.asPath) {
      props.history.push(nextRouter.asPath);
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

Then add that component to a `Route` inside the `BrowserRouter`. It is important that the route has `path="*"` if it is supposed to run on all routes.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="*" component={RouteIfStaleUrl} />
  // other stuff ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Forked Codesandbox with the fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-react-router-fix-updates-sug4s

[image: Fix as shown in Codesandbox]